# Login to website redirect to url and get htmlsource of new page?

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I'm trying to get html source after login a website with a userdata, but It doesn't give me html source of the new page It gives me login page htmlsource. So where is the problem in my source code?On the website it redirects me to a server select page after login "lobby.ogame.gameforge.com/?language=tr"; I'm trying to get html source of this page.

And this is my code;

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string URI = "https://tr.ogame.gameforge.com/";
        string myParameters = "login=testusername&pass=testpassword";

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
            richTextBox1.Text = HtmlResult;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Username and password are not sent via URL parameters to log you into a website. If they ever are, then I guarantee that's a site you don't want to be at.

Comment: So how i should make it ? @Marathon55

Comment: Try something similar to the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51672451/8534588)